# Grep Extract whole word without quotes

Tags: grep

I have a file with lot of entries in it. I want to extract the ID of certain component. The prefix of that ID is **abcd.inst**
Means there is only one word which is like

```
abcd.inst.sdt.gh-wer-1.anrg6ljrgo5rdtyc25lgtr2wf7iuhu2f5scwehpjjzerzpnphn3tzy4w2wjq
```

Whenever I do

```
cat abcd.txt | grep "abcd.inst"
```

I'm getting output as

```
"id": "abcd.inst.sdt.gh-wer-1.anrg6ljrgo5rdtyc25lgtr2wf7iuhu2f5scwehpjjzerzpnphn3tzy4w2wjq"
```

Is it anyway possible to get the Output as

```
abcd.inst.sdt.gh-wer-1.anrg6ljrgo5rdtyc25lgtr2wf7iuhu2f5scwehpjjzerzpnphn3tzy4w2wjq
```

I tired using

```
grep -oh abcd.inst abcd.txt
```

But the output was

```
abcd.inst
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome, can you share with us what have you tried so far? It's more likely that you will get help if you do.

Comment: I tried using "grep -oh abcd.inst abcd.txt" 

But there I got output as 
abcd.inst

Comment: Is `abcd.txt` by any chance a JSON file? It would be straightforward to extract any part of that file's data if one knew the document's structure.  You are showing a fragment, and it's impossible to tell where in the document structure this data occurs. A JSON parser would also decode the extracted information if needed.

Comment: @Am3Y [edit] the question adding what you wrote in the comment.

Comment: Not exactly a json file. But there are lot of text in it.

"id": "abcd.inst.sdt.gh-wer-1.anrg6ljrgo5rdtyc25lgtr2wf7iuhu2f5scwehpjjzerzpnphn3tzy4w2wjq"

------
"abcd.inst" this is the only keyword present in whole file.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to post an example extract from the file, so that contributors can better understand the context and possible pitfalls.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Sure I'll edit the whole question

Comment: @Am3Y Please don't answer in comments, but edit your question adding the new info. This way it's available for anyone wanting to pitch in without digging it up from commentaries.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the `"id:"` and quotation marks `"`, you could pipe the `grep` through `cut` and/or `sed`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Can you please give me a command for that? Like grep, sed anything would work as I will be using this in bash script.

Comment: `cat abcd.txt | grep "abcd.inst" | sed 's/"//g' | cut -c 5-` - **_However_** this is valid _only_ for the line you provided as an example. I can't guarantee it'll work for your entire file as I've no clue how the file looks like. There are more elegant solutions, for example I'm sure `sed` alone is sufficient - I don't know it well enough. Also see @Carson's answer.

Comment: Please remember to use the tick mark alongside the answer that helped you best. This shows the question was answered for you

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o` will output only the text of the match, which is why `grep -o abcd.inst` only prints `abcd.inst`.  The solution is to use regex to capture the entire output. `grep -oP 'abcd.inst[^"]+'` will do what you want. The `-P` flag enables perl-style patterns, and the pattern has been modified to match up the next quotation mark. [Here's a link](https://regex101.com/r/UrFvmF/1) to a tool that explains exactly what the pattern does.

Comment: Thank you everyone :)

Comment: `abcd.inst[^"]+` is a POSIX extended regular expression, which GNU `grep` handles with its `-E` option (so no need for `-P`). This makes it more portable to other `grep` implementations.  The POSIX basic regular expression equivalent would be `abcd.inst[^"]\{1,\}`.  Note that `.` matches any character (in all types of regular expression), so the expression would also match substrings like `0123abcdeinstrumental`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is a JSON document, we should parse it with a JSON parser.  Doing that without knowing where we may find the `id` key in the document is awkward but possible.  Below, we use `jq` to extract all the values from any `id` key in the whole document if the value starts with the string `abcd.inst`.

```bsh
jq -r ' .. |
        select( type == "object" and
                has("id") and
                (.id | startswith("abcd.inst"))
        ).id' file.json
```

We may also pass the string we're looking for on the command line to `jq`.

```bsh
jq -r --arg string 'abcd.inst' '
        .. |
        select( type == "object" and
                has("id") and
                (.id | startswith($string))
        ).id' file.json
```

---

If we treat the document as plain text, we may use `sed` to extract the string we want to find.  Doing so assumes that the data looks like in the question text, with no other data on the same line as the `"id":` and `"abcd.inst` substrings.  We must also assume that the string we are extracting does not contain embedded double quotes and that it does not need decoding from having been encoded in any way.

```bsh
sed     -e '/^[[:blank:]]*"id":[[:blank:]]*"abcd\.inst/!d' \
        -e 's/"[^"]*$//' \
        -e 's/.*"//' file
```

The `sed` command above deletes any line in the file that does not start with `"id":` followed by `"abcd.inst` (with optional spaces or tabs at the start of the line and between the two specified substrings).

The two subsequent substitutions trim the lines that we don't delete in the above way. The first substitution removes the last double-quote on the line and everything after it. The second substitution deletes everything from the start of the line up to the final double-quote in the line resulting from the first substitution.

After these operations, the substring we're looking for remains of the line, and `sed` outputs it to the terminal.